# Enable java plugin for Internet Explorer without installing java

Tags: java, internet-explorer, plugins, windows-7, applet

I have to access a website that have applet to encrypt the entered passwords before sending to server.

Problem i am having is that I haven't installed java using installer but only added to system path in the environment variable.

Now how can enable java plugin for Internet Explorer

Regards 
Mayuran

Comment: For downvoters: It is nicely formulated question asking for solving real problem. So, why down vote without any comment?

Answer (score 1):

Googled : adding java to internet explorer the first result is your answer.

https://java.com/en/download/help/enable_browser.xml

Follow these instructions to enable Java though your Web browser.

Internet Explorer

1. Click Tools and then Internet Options
2. Select the Security tab, and select the Custom Level button
3. Scroll down to Scripting of Java applets
4. Make sure the Enable radio button is checked
5. Click OK to save your preference

To install java in IE follow the steps mentioned:

1. Go to Java.com and click on the Free Java Download button
2. On the Internet Explorer download page click the download button to start the installation process
3. The File Download dialog box appears prompting you to run or save the download file
     To run the installer, click Run.
     To save the file for later installation, click Save.
4. Double-click on the saved file to start the installation process.
   The installation process starts. Click the Install button to accept the license terms and to continue with the installation.

https://www.java.com/en/download/help/ie_online_install.xml